# Do Browsers have eyelashes?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I'm reading this:

> De todas formas, es importante apuntar que el objeto de Session no es
>   compartido entre distintos usuarios, ni siquiera entre distintas
>   pestañas del navegador

... and, in my mind, I'm translating it to myself thus:

> In any case, it's important to note that the purpose of Session is not
>   to differentiate between users, not even between different "pestañas"
>   of the browser.

"*pestañas*"? What's that, I say to myself. I feed it to google translate, and get, "eyelashes."

Was zum Teufel ist hier los?

Could it be "instance"? I guess that kind of makes sense - after all, you blink your eyelash[es] in an instant...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Pestaña" in this context refers to the **"tabs"** of the Internet browser.

Nothing to do with the eyes, but with Internet.

You can see more info in Wikipedia: [Pestaña (informática)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesta%C3%B1a_(inform%C3%A1tica))

Answer (score 8):

El nombre de *pestañas* en los interfaces gráficos de usuario (y, por tanto, del navegador) viene de la similitud en aspecto y funcion con las pestañas que permiten seleccionar y abrir las carpetas en los archivadores.

Ejemplo: [Carpetas colgantes con pestaña lateral](http://www.amazon.es/Leitz-19863035-Alpha-Carpetas-colgantes/dp/B000KJRCMA) (de la tienda Amazon, este enlace puede quedar obsoleto pronto, pero sin duda se puede buscar en google "Carpetas con pestaña" obteniendo un resultado análogo)

Este nombre viene de la acepción número 4 de la siguiente definición en el [diccionario de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/):

> pestaña. (De or. inc.).
>
> 1. f. Cada uno de los pelos que hay en los bordes de los párpados, para defensa de los ojos.
> 2. f. Adorno estrecho que se pone al canto de las telas o vestidos, de fleco, encaje o cosa semejante, que sobresale algo.
> 3. f. Orilla o extremidad del lienzo, que dejan las costureras para que no se vayan los hilos en la costura.
> 4. f. Parte saliente y estrecha en el borde de alguna cosa; como en la llanta de una rueda de locomotora, en la orilla de un papel o una
>      plancha de metal, etc.
> 5. f. pl. Bot. Pelos rígidos que están colocados en el borde de una superficie.

Como siempre, en el caso de una traducción de textos técnicos, recomiendo huir de *innovaciones* por originales y creativas que puedan ser y atenerse estrictamente a los términos usados comunmente.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [fedorqui´s answer (*pestañas are tabs*)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13511/5481) *pestañas* could not be translated as **instances** as you propose in the question.

Depending on the operating system, I could have more that one instance of the same browser active at any time. I don't think that Mac/OS X allows this, but in Windows for example you could have more than one window running Firefox or Chrome. Each one of these windows would be an instance and each one could have its own tabs. Bottom line, `instance` has a complete different meaning as what is intended by *tab/pestaña*.

Comment: Diego: you can run two instances, but it requieres launching them from the command line or fooling Finder by duplicating the application and launching the second copy.